# C++: does std::invoke need perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding, std-invoke

Snippet

```
template <typename CallableType, typename... Args>
auto invokeTest(CallableType&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Is `std::forward<Args>` needed here?
Or is it enough to write

```
template <typename CallableType, typename... Args>
auto invokeTest(CallableType&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::invoke(fn, args...);
}
```

What are the differences?

Comment: create usage example where argument is `std::unique_ptr` and see what will happen. (it will fail to compile without perfect forwarding)

Comment: actually it depends on your needs. `std::invoke` can work without forwarded parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'd say yes but it depends on the case.

You don't need forwarding in that case:

```
void bar(int);

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    invokeTest(bar, i);
}
```

But, you'll need forwarding for this case:

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int>);

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>();
    invokeTest(foo, p); // Won't work, cannot copy unique_ptr
}
```

When writing `std::invoke(fn, args...)`, the `args...` are all lvalues, at which point I would recommend taking parameters by `Args const&...` to be clearer.

If you forward, then you move the object that were rvalues in your parameters:

```
template <typename CallableType, typename... Args>
auto invokeTest(CallableType&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...); // all forward value caterories
}

invokeTest(foo, std::move(p)); // works.
```

If you use `Args&&...`, use forwarding.